# JQuery UI + Seaside set-up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, smalltalk, seaside

Which package(s) do I need to load for jQuery UI in Seaside?

Currently I have these installed/loaded:

- Pharo Seaside One-Click Image
- Added the jQuery repository to the Monticello Browser (Squeaksource - jQuery)
- Loaded jQuery-EL.10.mcz

However when I run this [example](http://demo.seaside.st/seaside/tests/jquery-ui/droppableinteraction?_s=vfUG-GPTxVKbYx58&_k=V-tJk9FkJ4vhYFnC) I get the error "MessageNotUnderstood: WARenderCanvas>>jQuery"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[builder.seaside.st](http://builder.seaside.st/) should give you a working load script for any possible configuration. Make sure to check *jQuery and jQueryUI* and then click on *Load Script* to download a script that you can drag & drop onto a [Pharo Dev Image](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/24976/pharo1.0-10500-rc1dev09.12.1.zip). Note, that jQuery is not available for Seaside 2.8.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I was working with Seaside 2.8. I have loaded the Seaside 3 script, and it looks like I can now use jQuery. However, I'm not sure how to start the server now.

Comment: In the world menu (click on the desktop background) click on *Tools*, *More...*, and *Seaside Control Panel*. Then right click on the listing and select *Add Adaptor*, give a port number and click on *start*.

Alternatively evaluate in a workspace: WAKom startOn: 8080

Comment: I didn't find the Seaside control panel, but WAKom startOn: 8080 worked. Thanks a lot!